# use property when write a class for objective-c,is there still need declare instance variant

Tags: objective-c

the first i use the property is follower the book,so the code is like this

```c
//
//  StockHolding.h
//  17.6 Stocks
//
//  Created by Sen on 6/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 SLboat. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject
{   // did we really need doing this again?what's good for?
    float _purchasePrice;
    float _currentSharePrice;
    int numberOfShares;
}
@property float purchasePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int   numberOfShares;

- (float)costInDollars;
- (float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

but i found if i dont declare the instant variant,it will work as well too.

```
//
//  StockHolding.h
//  17.6 Stocks
//
//  Created by Sen on 6/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 SLboat. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StockHolding : NSObject

@property float purchasePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int   numberOfShares;

- (float)costInDollars;
- (float)valueInDollars;

@end
```

so didi we need those instance variant declaration.

Comment: books are outdated pretty fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not plan on supporting old version of mac, iOS, and Xcode then no. You do not have to declare your ivars and @property/@synthasize them. This is the old way of doing things where newer version of the compiler take care of this for you. I believe this was introduced with Xcode 4.4 & Mac OSX 8 (Mountain lion).

Newer version will take this.

```
@property float purchasePrice;
@property float currentSharePrice;
@property int   numberOfShares;
```

And create you three ivars

```
float _purchasePrice;
float _currentSharePrice;
int _numberOfShares;
```

each with their own getter & setters.

Books are a great place to start, but they are quickly outdated. This is especially true in a language like Objective-C. The team that governs that language & clang introduce a good amount of changes at each years WWDC. I would continue to read through your book, but don't forget there are a lot of good resources over at apple free of charge. I would recommend looking at the [programming with Objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2).

Additionally, to clarify the answer to your question here is a section of the document I just referenced.

> Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has
>   the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a
>   property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance
>   variable will be called _firstName.

*edit*
I copied the wrong section of the document.

Comment: Agreed. The only exception is that if you override the getters and setters with custom implementations (or for readonly properties, if you override the getter), then you have to manually `@synthesize`. Other than that, you just declare the properties and the modern compilers will automatically  `@synthesize` for you (as well as creating the backing ivars and the accessor methods).

Comment: It would be better if you quote this paragraph ***By default, a readwrite property will be backed by an instance variable, which will again be synthesized automatically by the compiler.***

Comment: Wow!that's very clean answer thank you all guys!the Apple book I have never read one yet ,but I think then have lot thing on it.the book I read now is the big nerd ranch 's ios programmer. Thank you you guys are great obj-c